# MongoDB Query Based on ObjectId Reference Condition

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate, robo3t

I have a MongoDB collection `Cats` that has a ObjectId reference field `zooId` to collection `Zoo`.

How would I go about querying something like

`db.Cats.find({zooId.zooName: 'San Diego'}).count()`

where the condition of the query is of a field `zooName` in the `zooId` reference?

I understand by using Mongoose, I can call the `populate` method to actually fetch certain references, but how would I do similar things directly in the mongodb console or RoboMongo?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simple coding:

```
var cats = 0;
db.Zoo.find({zooName: 'San Diego'}).forEach(function(zooItem){
   var id = zooItem._id;
   cats += db.Cat.find({'zooId' : id}).count();
});

print(cats);
```